# No puedo enviar correos a múltiples remitentes con python smtplib

Tags: python-2.7, email, smtp

Buenas tardes comunidad.
Estoy creando un script en python 2.7.13 para enviar correo a multiples destinos con un archivo adjunto.
Pero solo me lo envía al primero de la lista de correos que tengo.
A pesar de esto, lo otros correos de mi lista aparecen en el email que me llega a mi bandeja de entrada desde mi script.

Importo lo necesario para crear mi script.

```py
# send_attachment.py
# import necessary packages
from email.mime.multipart import MIMEMultipart
from email.MIMEImage import MIMEImage
from email.mime.text import MIMEText
from email.mime.base import MIMEBase
from email import encoders 
import smtplib
import mimetypes
```

Aquí es creo mi lista de correo de destino.

```py
msg = MIMEMultipart()



Destino=['correo1@gmail.com','correo2@gmail.com','correo3a@gmail.com','correo4@gmail.com' ]

password = "mipassword"
msg['From'] = "micorreo@gmail.com"
msg['To'] = ','.join(Destino)
msg['Subject'] = "Enviando un correo a mas de un destino"
```

Compruebo y adjunto el tipo de archivo enviado

```py
ctype, encoding = mimetypes.guess_type("prueba1.csv")
if ctype is None or encoding is not None:
    ctype="applecation/actet-stream"

maintype, subtype = ctype.split("/",1)

#Se adjunta archivo y se configura 
fp=open("prueba1.csv","rb")
adjunto=MIMEBase(maintype,subtype)
adjunto.set_payload(fp.read())
fp.close()
encoders.encode_base64(adjunto)
adjunto.add_header("Content-Disposition","adjunto",filename="prueba1.csv")



msg.attach(adjunto)
```

Creo el server y envío el correo (con un mensaje de correo enviado exitosamente)

```py
server = smtplib.SMTP('smtp.gmail.com: 587')
server.starttls()


server.login(msg['From'], password)


server.sendmail(msg['From'], msg['To'], msg.as_string())

server.quit()

print "successfully sent email to %s:" % (msg['To'])
```

El problema no es con el archivo adjunto, si no que solo se me envía al primer correo de mi lista.

Alguien tiene una idea de lo que pueda pasar? 
o como solucionarlo?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

El protocolo SMTP usa un "sobre" (*envelope*) que especifica cada una de las direcciones a las que el servidor repartirá el mensaje.  El sobre nunca será visible al usuario final, pues una vez el mensaje llega a destino el sobre es destruido.

Por otro lado, dentro de ese "sobre" va el mensaje, el cual contiene muchas cabeceras, entre las que se halla la cabecera "To:", en la que habitualmente vemos la lista de destinatarios.

Sin embargo, nada obliga a que ambas listas coincidan. En el sobre puede aparecer una lista de destinatarios diferente a la que aparece después en las cabeceras del mensaje. Esto es lo que ocurre si usas el campo Bcc a la hora de escribir un mensaje. Las direcciones que pongas en Bcc se usarán en el sobre, y el propio campo Bcc desaparecerá del mensaje con lo que quienes reciben ese mensaje no sabrán quién más lo ha recibido.

En tu caso creas la cabecera "To:" correcta en estas líneas:

```
Destino=['correo1@gmail.com','correo2@gmail.com','correo3a@gmail.com','correo4@gmail.com' ]
msg['To'] = ','.join(Destino)
```

lo cual se usará sólo para el mensaje, pero no para el sobre. El sobre se crea en cambio cuando llamas a esta función:

```
server.sendmail(msg['From'], msg['To'], msg.as_string())
```

El primer parámetro de `sendmail()` será la dirección de correo a la que debe entregarse el mensaje si éste "rebota" (no se puede entregar a destino). Puedes poner lo mismo que en la cabecera "From:" del mensaje, u otra cosa.

El segundo parámetro es el destinatario o lista de ellos. Esta función python asumirá un solo destinatario si lo que le pasas es una cadena (como es tu caso), o varios si es una lista. Pero en tu caso lo has usado mal, puesto que le has enviado una lista de usuarios en forma de cadena. Lo que ocurra en este caso depende de cómo maneje el servidor al que te has conectado esa cadena separada por comas. Se ve que Gmail se queda sólo con la primera dirección.

Por tanto la **solución** será pasarle a esta función una lista en vez de una cadena:

```
server.sendmail(msg['From'], Destino, msg.as_string())
```